# What is the location of OpenOffice.org templates in Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, openoffice.org

I'd like to install some presentation templates, but don't know where to put them...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose Tools > Options > OpenOffice.org > Paths and select the Templates line. There you can click "edit" and see the paths that it uses to search for templates.

Answer (score 1):

```
/usr/lib/openoffice/share/template/
```

That's on a Debian Lenny/testing. You can find them by typing

```
locate .ots
```

in a console (ots being the extension of OOo templates)

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to place templates in  /usr/lib/openoffice/... because the contents of that folder can be altered automatically through the process of Debian package management. For site-wide installation I created the folder "/usr/local/share/templates/ooo2/common", placed templates in there, then added the path to the set of paths mentioned above.